# How can I force Thunderbird to use a profile opened with a newer version?

Tags: thunderbird, compatibility, user-profiles, downgrade

I have recently used a beta of a newer version of Thunderbird, and my existing profile. Now, I want to use the previous, non-beta version with that same profile, but am getting an error message about possible changes by the newer version which are no longer compatible etc. etc.

Well, I want to force Thunderbird to use this profile anyway. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

See if you can downgrade the Profile.

[Downgrade Thunderbird Profile](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1348261)

> If you're sure there's only one TB program installed, try launching
> Profile Manager from a Run window (Winkey+R): type thunderbird.exe -p
> --allow-downgrade

If that does not work, you may need to use the Beta Version until Production catches up.

Comment: I tried this, and got the same message. How can I _manually_ downgrade though?

Comment: It downgrading does not work, then the only other way is (as I posted), use the Beta version of Thunderbird until Production catches up.

Comment: How come? After all, the settings are compatible, the main folders are compatible, the address book is compatible etc. etc.

Comment: There is an incompatibility between the old TB version and the new profile.  The only way forward I can see is to use the Beta version

Answer (score 1):

i had the same problem (thunderbird.exe -p --allow-downgrade not working)

i deleted **compatibility.ini** from my profile folder and ran "**thunderbird.exe -p --allow-downgrade**" again. It worked fine.

BUT I downgraded to a recent version of TB (had 117 beta 1 and went back to 115.1). I guess it could create an issue if the versions are too far apart.